# Custom post type and custom taxonomy 404 on page 2

Tags: custom-post-types, php, wp-query, custom-taxonomy, pagination

I have the exact same issue as [Custom Taxonomy archive returns 404](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/241386/custom-taxonomy-archive-returns-404), I tried implementing the solution but still finding issues...

here is my CPT

```
    <?php
    if( ! function_exists( 'videos_create_post_type' ) ) :
        function videos_create_post_type() {
            $labels = array(
                'name' => 'Videos',
                'singular_name' => 'Video',
                'add_new' => 'Add video',
                'all_items' => 'All videos',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add video',
                'edit_item' => 'Edit video',
                'new_item' => 'New video',
                'view_item' => 'View video',
                'search_items' => 'Search videos',
                'not_found' => 'No videos found',
                'not_found_in_trash' => 'No videos found in trash',
                'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent video'
            );
            $args = array(
                'labels' => $labels,
                'public' => true,
                'has_archive' => 'videos',
                'publicly_queryable' => true,
                'query_var' => true,
                'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'videos/%videos_category%', 'with_front' => false ),
                'capability_type' => 'post',
                'hierarchical' => false,
                'supports' => array(
                    'title',
                    'editor',
                    'thumbnail',
                    'revisions'
                ),
                'menu_position' => 5,
                'menu_icon'     => 'dashicons-video-alt3',
                'exclude_from_search' => false
            );
            register_post_type( 'videos', $args );
            //flush_rewrite_rules();

            register_taxonomy( 'videos_category', // register custom taxonomy - category
                'videos',
                array(
                    'hierarchical' => true,
                    'public' => true,
                    'show_admin_column' => true,
                    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
                    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'videos', 'with_front' => false ),
                    'labels' => array(
                        'name' => 'Video categories',
                        'singular_name' => 'Video category',
                    )
                )
            );
        }
        add_action( 'init', 'videos_create_post_type' );

        function wpa_show_permalinks( $post_link, $post ){
            $args = array(
                'orderby'   => 'ID',
                'order'     => 'ASC'
            );
            if ( is_object( $post ) && $post->post_type == 'videos' ){
                $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'videos_category', $args );
                if( $terms ){
                    return str_replace( '%videos_category%' , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
                }
            }
            return $post_link;
        }

    endif; // end of function_exists()
?>
```

I still get 404's on page/2
my loop props on my archive template is set up like this

```
                <?php
                    global $post;
                    $custom_taxterms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'videos_category', array('fields' => 'ids') );
                    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
                    $args = array(
                        'posts_per_page' => 1,
                        'is_paged' => true,
                        'post_type' => 'videos',
                        'paged' => $paged,
                        'tax_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'videos_category',
                                'field' => 'id',
                                'terms' => $custom_taxterms
                            )
                        ),
                    );
                    $custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );
                ?>
```

And in the while loop i just pass

```
                @while ($custom_query->have_posts()) @php($custom_query->the_post())
                    @include('partials.content-'.get_post_type())
                @endwhile
```

I'm using blade templating incase you were wondering about the @while etc.

Help would be much appreciated :)
Thanks!

Comment: What does return your loop on page 1 ? If you're on a taxonomy archive page I don't understand why you have to make you're own WP Query.

Comment: Hey man, this returns all posts related to specific categories (my taxonomy videos_categories) and lets me limit the amount of posts without using the standard admin setting.

Comment: Ok, if you're looking to change the limits of `posts_per_page` only, you must use `pre_get_post` hook instead of a new query, tell me if you need the answer, but you can find what you ant here : https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts

Comment: Cheers for that, i tried:

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $query ) {
    if ( is_post_type_archive( 'videos' ) ) {
        // Display 2 posts for a custom post type called 'videos'
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 2 );
        return;
    }
} );


But no luck in changing the amount shown... probably because i'm in a taxonomy page (category) rather than a straight up archive page just showing all video post types?

Comment: I've tried extending this with
`add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_tax( 'videos_category' ) && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $terms = get_terms( 'videos_category', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
  $query->set( 'videos', array( 'post' ) );
  $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 2 );
        $query->set( 'tax_query', array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'videos_category',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $terms
            )
        ) );
    }
    return $query;} );`

Comment: But I still get the 404 on /page/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after many trials and errors, I found I had to create a specific rewrite rule to go into my functions.php, one that handles post type '**videos**' and the category (taxonomy) '**videos_category**':

```
add_filter('init', function() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 
        '^videos/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(\d*)?',
        'index.php?videos_category=$matches[1]&p=$matches[2]&paged=$matches[3]',
        'top' 
     ); 
});
```

I also found this plugin to be really helpful for viewing my rewrite rules:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite-rules-inspector/